sovereign credit default swap CDS currency conversion on Refinitiv DataStream
I have download the sovereign CDS 5y spread mid of the 69 countries with available datasets from the Refinitiv DataStream database.
when I apply the currency conversion to all of them, I get an error notification with no data returned. But if I request for the data without currency conversion (just the local currency) I get data returned to me.
How do I harmonize the datasets under one currency (USD)?

Have you tried asking Refinitiv tech support?

yes, i did. no response

CDS quotes cannot be reliably converted from one currency to another using just interest rates. In theory, in perfectly liquid and efficient markets, it would be easy to calculate the risk-free probabilities of default from CDS quotes and one currency's interest rates, then back to CDS quotes using another currency's interest rates, but this isn't exactly how markets really work. In reality, the ratio of CDS spreads in different currencies - the quanto factors - are market observables with term structure, often fluctuate .95-1.05 or more, may be available from Totem and/or Refinitiv, and are driven by supply and demand. E.g. someone is building a CDO denominatee in some currency, trading and moving components single-name CDS protection in this currency, but not moving as much CDS on the same names in other currencies. For sovereigns and quasi-sovereigns CDS protection in local currency, the quanto factors may be as low as .4-.6 because of assumed devaluation upon default. E.g. if Italy or France sovereigns default, then EUR will devalue v USD et al, therefore EUR-denominated CDS protection is cheaper than than USD et al, but you can't guess by how much - rather, you need to see how the market prices it. Similarly, US sovereign CDS protection in USD and in EUR are two different animals.

Thank you so much for your response. the real challenge I am having is that I wish to use the bps of the CDS to run a regression analysis comparing several countries with different currency denominated CDS and I am troubled that it may not reflect the real situation

If I wanted a regression of the US and Italy sovereign CDS spreads, I'd probably just use EUR denominated US and USD denominated Italiy to represent the market view of probability of default and loss given default. I'd avoid respective local currency - USD US and EUR Italy - since that additionally includes market view of devaluation on default.

Note also that because EU banned "naked" sovereign CDS in 2011 (see https://ec.europa.eu/commission/presscorner/api/files/document/print/en/memo_11_713/MEMO_11_713_EN.pdf for example) comparing their CDS with other sovereigns' CDS may be less meaningful. For other sovereigns, just pick for each name some non-local currency, not necessarily the same for all names, that's the most liquid - to minimize the effects of devaluation on default and technical supply and demand.

Thank you so much dear Dimitri, this has been very helpful
